# Home work help I am stuck at NUmber 6 Window.prompt() step

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my coding.. What have I done wrong. I am on number 6 and it is not working  Can someone please look at this and give me some help.?
Thanks

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> My Homework </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:400px; height:200px" id="firstdiv">
     <br /> <br /><center>Well Hi there! <br/> Answer the prompt to see what happens next.</center>
    </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     var moquestion = window.prompt("What is the capital of Missouri?","");

     if (moquestion.length < 1) {
        <div style="width:400px; height:200px" id="sorrydiv">
          <br /> <br /> <h1><center>Sorry you don't feel like playing.<br />The capital of Missouri is Jefferson City</center></h1>
        </div>
      }
   </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the assignment

1. Create a webpage with all the basic HTML tags.
2. Inside the `<body>`, create a `<div>` tag with an element id.
3. Insert some text into the `<div>` tag.
4. Add your script below this `<div>` so that it will not attempt to run until the  has loaded.
5. Use the window.prompt method to ask “What is the capital of Missouri?” Ensure that no default answer is displayed for the user.
6. Check to make sure the length property of the returned string is not less than 1. If it is empty, write something like the following into the `<div>` tag: “Sorry you don’t feel like playing. The capital of Missouri is Jefferson City.”
7. If the string is not empty, use the window.confirm method to ask the user: “Is that your final answer?”
8. If they confirm, write a string similar to the following into the  tag: “The capital of Missouri is” + myanswer + “. So says you.”
9. If they cancel, ask the question again: “Well then what is the capital of Missouri?” This time, write the answer without error checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you are using HTML-Code within your JavaScript code.

The `<script type="text/javascript">`-tag tells your browser: Execute the next block using your default JavaScript-Engine. But JavaScript Engines aren't able to render or even understand HTML Code.

Start creating a simple template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Homework No. 6</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <!-- place the script at the bottom to execute 
        AFTER the whole page has loaded. -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // create the DIV Tag and insert it
            // Answers: question 2 & 3

            // THIS IS WHERE THE HTML-ELEMENT KICKS INTO THE PAGE
            var div= document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = "Lets play!";
            div.id = "questionContainer";

            // Insert the element into the body
            document.body.appendChild(div);


            var question = window.prompt("What is the capital of Missouri", "");

            // check if the question is empty
            if (question.length < 1 || typeof question === "undefined") {
                div.innerHTML = "Sorry you don't feel like playing :(";
                return;
           }
           // check if user is sure (and repeat the question if he's not.)
           if (!window.confirm("Are you sure?")) 
                question = window.prompt("What is the capital of Missouri", "");

           div.innerHTML = "The capital of Missouri is: " + question + " as you told me.";
       </script>
    <body>
</html>
```

This should solve the problem. Just remember: Do not mix JavaScript and HTML.

Also: Check out this jsFiddle to view it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/du4CH/

Comment: Thank you for the help.. you all have seriously helped me.  I got myself confused and couldn't get out of the train of thought!   That you for pointing me in the right direct!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean write a new `div` tag, it means to change the contents of the tag you've already written, the one you called "firstdiv".

Comment: Wow... I should have known that..  What a silly mistake.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Point 6 is actually saying to "write it into the div tag". Assuming that it means the div that you created earlier you should be looking at locating the div on the document and then writing to its innerHTML. Something like

```
if (moquestion.length < 1) {
    document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML="Sorry you don't feel like playing";
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you.   You all have been a great help!  =)  I feel like such an idiot